The origins and development of the Riemannian curvature tensor
I have been reading about the Riemannian curvature tensor and am curious about its historical development. Specifically, I would like to understand the following:
Firstly, Who were the key mathematicians involved in the early formulation and refinement of this concept?.
Secondly, how did earlier ideas of curvature in geometry influence the eventual definition of the Riemannian curvature tensor?
I am particularly interested in digging deeper into Riemann’s contributions and how his work laid the foundation for this concept. I would also like to know how this idea evolved and was later expanded upon, particularly its connections to other fields such as Einstein’s general theory of relativity.
If there are any recommended references—books, papers, or historical accounts—that provide insight into the evolution of this concept within mathematics and physics, I would highly appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Welcome to History of Science and Mathematics SE. Have you done any previous research? If not try that and edit your question to make it more precise, we remove posts that have too many questions in one.

@Mauricio The fact is that I do not know any source to start with and that is hindering me from doing enough research. I have tried to look for resources on the internet but without any guidance, I ended up reaching nowhere.

Your question is still very broad, it might get closed. Read this https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/15041/did-riemann-invent-the-riemann-curvature-tensor and see if it helps you reduce the number of question.

@Mauricio I just edited my question a bit. Does it seem to be more focused now?

As you have converted this into a reference request question, I have retracted my close vote

An expansive treatment, albeit it in German, is:

Reich, K. (1994) Die Entwicklung des Tensorkalküls: vom absoluten
Differentialkalkül zur Relativitätstheorie. Springer.

(For a rapid overview in English see Reich, K. (1994) Differential geometry. In: Companion encyclopedia of the history and philosophy of the mathematical sciences, Vol. 1, Ivor Grattan-Guiness (ed). , p. 331-341.)
Another useful source on Riemann specifically is the multi-chapter historical commentary by Jost in his edited edition of Riemann's Hypotheses:

Jost, J. (ed.) (2016) Bernhard Riemann - On the hypotheses which lie at the bases of
geometry. Birkhäuser. Historical Commentaries by Jost on p. 9-28, 119-146, 147-153.

The following collection contains a range of contributions of potential interest:

Ji, L., Papadopoulos, A., & Yamada, S. (eds.) (2017) From Riemann
to differential geometry and relativity. Springer.

